# SpriteRenderer broken after loading scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a GameObject with `SpriteRenderer` in a scene. When I run scene directly, everyting is fine. The problem is when scene is loaded from other scene via `Application.LoadLevel`.

Although `SpriteRender` is enabled, texture is not visible in a game. I need to re-enable component in Inspector to make it work. What could be a cause?

Comment: Probably you are using the same texture in a previous level. When you change levels the previous level is unloading all of it's resources, including textures. It's done asynchronously so probably the texture is being unloaded AFTER the new level has loaded it. You can explicitly tell unity not to unload stuff if you need.

Comment: The problem is that the texture is not used in previous scenes.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? Try moving the texture to the **Resources** folder and Call Resources.Load(). But obviously this should not be necessary.

Comment: Hm.. solved. It turned out that Order in layer was wrong (the same as background sprite). The strange part is that when scene is loaded directly drawing order was background and then my sprite. When Loaded from other scene, that order was changed. Anyway - thanks!

Comment: @pwas- I'm experiencing a similar issue. What exact order did you set everything to? And how did you fix the issue where it was drawing in the incorrect order? Currently, I have set my player to -1, the enemies to 0, and the background to 1.